# Echo directories as numbers in bash for loop

Tags: bash

For example, I looped through the dirs in current directory:

```
for s in ./*/;
do
    echo $s
done
./4014/
./4015/
./4017/
./4018/
```

My question is how to make the loop using each dir as it were a single number such like:

```
4014
4015
4017
4018
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove the trailing `/`:

```
for folder in */; do
    echo "${folder%/}"
done
```

Or if you want to loop in other directories:

```
for folder in path/*/; do
    folder=${folder%/}
    echo "${folder##*/}"
done
```

You can also use `basename`:

```
for folder in path/*/; do
    basename "${folder}"
done
```

Quote expansions!

Answer (score 0):

With **`find`** command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: The find would do a recursive search, whereas I believe OP was looking only in current directory.   You could use `-maxdepth 1` to accomplish this with find though.